# Label two summarize columns of groupby in matplotlib (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Using Pandas I want to groupby one column and than summarize two others.
Which I'm doing like that:

```
df.groupby('data')['Time \n[h]', 'Time \n[h].1'].sum().plot(kind='line')
```

And I get nice plot but how can I label each column. E.g 'Us' instead of 'Time \n[h]' and 'Them' instead of 'Time \n[h].1'

(sorry for strange title but I'm not even sure how to call it)

Thanks,
Submi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is rename columns first by `dict`:

```
df1 = df.rename(columns={'Time \n[h]':'Us','Time \n[h].1':'Them'})
df1.groupby('data')['Us', 'Them'].sum().plot(kind='line')
```

Or you can set `legend` text:

```
ax = df.groupby('data')['Time \n[h]', 'Time \n[h].1'].sum().plot(kind='line')
ax.legend(['Us','Them'])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[1,1,3],
                   'Time \n[h]':[4,5,6],
                   'Time \n[h].1':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   Time \n[h]  Time \n[h].1  data
0           4             7     1
1           5             8     1
2           6             9     3

df1 = df.rename(columns={'Time \n[h]':'Us','Time \n[h].1':'Them'})
df1.groupby('data')['Us', 'Them'].sum().plot()
```

[image: graph]